# method send on a socket in a non blocking mode and performance

Tags: c++, sockets

I am under Linux, I'm trying to measure the time a send on a socket take time.

```
auto timePoint1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto result = ::send(m_socket, data, dataSize, MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_DONTWAIT );    

auto timePoint2 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto diff = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(timePoint2 - timePoint1)
```

I call the above code ~18 millions time. The results on my server are between 2 microseconds and 17 microseconds, with a percentile 95% at 2.2 microseconds and a percentile 99% at 12.4 microsonds

What can explain this variance?
Is there a way to diminush it a maximum ?

Comment: Most likely, the variance depends on whether there's a context switch or not. If, for example, a process with higher dynamic priority is waiting for the core, a context switch will take place.

Comment: I have set my process as the highest priority process on this server. `nice -15`

Comment: Then it may depend on whether a packet needs to be sent immediately or not.

Comment: Can you explain further please ? for information, I have set TCP_NODELAY option.

Comment: When you call `send`, the kernel may or may not need to send a packet immediately. If it does, it has more work to do, which may take longer. I'm not sure why you would think `TCP_NODELAY` changes that.

Comment: About TCP_NODELAY, I say this, just in case you will refer to it, but it is not the case visibly.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that the amount of work `send` has to do can vary. It may have to allocate more buffer space. It may not. It may have to send a packet. It may not. And so on.